# "val_acc" does not change at all

Tags: python, image-processing, deep-learning, keras, classification

I created a CNN for image classification using Keras on Python. I have a rather small data set(approx. 3000 pictures), the main goal is a simple binary classification.

And the issue is that **during the training the "acc" grows, while the "val_acc" doesn't change at all** from the very beginning and stays +- 0.6.

I searched the internet and almost everywhere people say that the main trouble is the small size of my data set, i.e. the net is **overfitting**. 
But I tried to make it as simple as possible (now it's 2 Conv layers, Flatten and 1 hidden FC layer), i added batch normalization and nothing helps!

Maybe there's something i don't understand and that's why it doesn't work? The longer I'm doing this, the more confused I get about **what's the difference between "acc" and "val_acc"** at all? I would be very grateful for any help!

P.S. I tried to use the code from the [Keras blog tutorial](https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html) about "Cats vs. Dogs" classification, but this didn't help to, the problem stays the same:(

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please post a [minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so that we can help you.

Comment: More important than acc is the `loss` (it must decrease). The difference between `loss` and `val_loss` is that one is measured with your training data, and the other is measured with your validation data. ---- Training data is the only one that your model uses to learn, while validation/test data is something you give to your model at the end, just to see if it was good enough to learn about images that it never saw before. --- If the training loss goes down, but the validation loss doesn't, it's very probably an overfitting problem: your model is too good.

Comment: There are other possibilities, such as: your validation data is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there are many cases where val_acc does not change at all,

In my case, I downloaded ResNet 50 and changed some layers to trainable=False. This resulted in constant val_acc of 0.5 while acc was going up.

Fix was to run model.compile(...) after changing the trainable attribute of the layers.